# google app engine ndb, filter after query: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: google-app-engine

The following statements generate an error message **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'**. I thought `filter` after `query` is perfectly OK. What was the problem then? Thanks in advance.

```
purchases = Purchase.query(Purchase.date>=startDate, Purchase.date<endDate)
...

purchases = purchases.filter(Purchase.account==member.account,
                             ndb.OR(Purchase.consumedMode=='bidding',
                                    Purchase.consumedMode=='purchasing')).fetch()
```

Comment: I think your usage is ok. The problem should be caused by something else. For example, may be you changed your purchases between the two sentance.

Answer (score 0):

If purchases is a query, filter works just fine.

If purchases is a list after retrieving the results of a query, it won't work, like

```
purchases = [item for item in purchases]
```

What happens in ... in your code?

Comment: OK, I found the bug. I did alter the purchases between the two sentences. Because the _distance_ is very long, I missed that. Sorry for bothering you guys. Your help is very much appreciated.